# SQL sorting issue

Tags: sql, oracle

The following request not return the result in the right order between the client and the server in oracle 12 c

```
SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS INDEX_ASC( IDX)  */
.... Union all
SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS INDEX_ASC(IDX) */
```

Comment: Don't use a hint to order rows.  Use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: There is no 'right order' in your query. [Obligatory Tom Kyte quote](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/order-in-court.html): "reading data out via an index - *does not imply data is sorted by the index key!*"

Comment: Why the use of a hint is not advisable ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an ORDER BY clause :

```
SELECT ...
UNION ALL SELECT ...
ORDER BY idx
```

The ORDER BY applies globally to result sets returned on each side of the UNION.

Comment: @jerevann : not sure that I understand your question... Would you please rephrase ?

Comment: If i use a query with the where clause that does not select all columns in the composite index, the asc hint has no effect ? Does the hint index asc do a sort ?

Comment: For example, if i have a table tableA with a composite index IDX_TA on columns B and C columns, using select /* + INDEX_ASC (IDX TA) */ B,C from tableA where B =1 and C=2 did not sort the result ? I should use an order by B asc, C asc to have an order result ?

Comment: Did someone could explian me why the use of the HINT INDEX_ASC in oracle 12c, not sort the result ? is a hint a recommendation or can he oracle bypass ?